# Read data from text file with long header

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to read the following text file into MATLAB:

```
Data from RamanShift_18-24-54-814.txt Node  
Date: Sun Feb 01 18:24:54 GMT 2015  
User:   
Spectrometer: QEP00413  
Autoset integration time: false 
Trigger mode: 4 
Integration Time (sec): 1.000000E0  
Scans to average: 1 
Electric dark correction enabled: true  
Nonlinearity correction enabled: false  
Boxcar width: 0 
XAxis mode: Wavelengths 
Stop averaging: false   
Number of Pixels in Spectrum: 1044  
-66.286 -2.5
-62.486 -0.5
-58.689 -0.5
-54.895 2.5
-51.104 40.5
-47.316 49.5
-43.531 52.5
```

I want to ignore the text at the beginning and load in the two numeric columns. I have tried this:

```
M = dlmread('RamanShift_18-24-54-814.txt','\t',190,0);
```

this fails with the following error:

```
Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 2u, field 1u) ==> \n
```

if I choose just the second column, by:

```
M = dlmread('RamanShift_18-24-54-814.txt','\t',190,1);
```

then this works, but the every other element of M is a zero?

```
1113.50000000000
0
1104.50000000000
0
1094.50000000000
0
1069.50000000000
0
```

1) How can I improve this to read in both columns and 2) to correct for the alternate zero problem?

Many Thanks,
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [**`importdata`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function

```
A = importdata('yourTextfile.txt','\t',14)
```

This line skips the first **14** lines of your file, as desired and uses the **tabulator** delimiter to read in the two data columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `textscan`, by default it uses white spaces as a separator. It will work perfect in your case:

```
fid = fopen('yourFileName.txt');
resCell = textscan(fid, '%s'); resCell = resCell{1};
fclose(fid);
```

Then you might search for a keyword that appears always in your file (like 'Spectrum:') and read the numbers:

```
startInd = find(strcmpi(resCell, 'Spectrum:'), 1) + 2; % 2 is a shift that you specify that depends in the keyword you chose.
```

Now:

```
nSamples = (numel(resCell) - ind + 1)/2; % this should be an even number in your case! I guess that this change between sampling sessions...
```

And:

```
data = reshape(str2double(resCell(startInd:end)), 2, nSamples);
```

Last but not least, have fun!

Comment: this does not have the desired result. It produces one long column of all the data mixed:'49.5
'
'-43.531'
'52.5
'
'-39.749'
'54.5
'
'-35.97'
'59.5
'
'-32.194'
'68.5
'
'-28.42'
'84.5
'
'-24.65'
'99.5
'
'-20.883'
'119.5
'
'-17.118'
The idea of searching is not required. All I want are two columns of data. row and column offsets would be ideal